# Django validation error messages only showing in admin page

Tags: python, django

I have a **SignUp** form that interacts with Django's user model to create new users. If password fields match, the user is successfully created and logged in. If password fields do not match, the user is not created, so I guess validation is working. But somehow, a validation error message is not shown, the form page is just rendered again. When I go to Django's admin page, the error messages pop up there! Why is it not popping in my template?!

This is my form:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password', 'class':'form-control', 'type':'password'}),)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Confirm Password', 'class':'form-control', 'type':'password'}),)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'First Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
               'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Last Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
               'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email', 'class':'form-control', 'type':'email'}),
               'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username', 'class':'form-control'}),
               'password': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password', 'class':'form-control', 'type':'password'})
               }

        fields = {'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password'}

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignUpForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match!')
```

**And this is my view:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)

            form.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Account created successfully!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "There's an error in the form! Please fill it again.")
            return render(request, 'form/register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'form/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**And this is my template:**

```
<div class="login-box-body">
        {% block login_form %}
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if form.errors %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p class="login-box-msg" style="color: red;">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    {{form.first_name}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    {{form.last_name}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    {{form.email}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    {{form.username}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    {{form.password}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    {{form.password2}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'manager:login' %}'">Voltar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Criar Conta</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        {% endblock login_form %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo: `{% for error in field.errors %}` should be `{% for error in form.errors %}`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I did what you said and now it shows "_ all _" as the error message. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to work it out, at least as a temporary solution! Daniel was right, there was a typo in my template, but it was showing "_ all _" as the error message, not sure why.

Since the password fields were the only ones I was using **raise forms.ValidationError** function, then the error message was only to be shown in case the passwords wasn't matching.

So I just wrote the error message I wanted directly in my template! Like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="login-box-msg" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Passwords do not match!</p>
    {% endif %}
```

It doesn't work the way I wanted, but it does the job!